Getting the wrong value when using the override toString method
I am using an arraylist to hold different shape objects that are a subclass of an abstract superclass. The superclass contains two abstract methods: surface_area and volume respectively. After I add the objects to my arraylist, I want to print to the console the results of the surface area and volume methods using an override for the toString method. However, when running the code, I just get 0.0 for the values instead of the actual value. What am I doing wrong?

public abstract class Shape {
    abstract double surface_area();
    abstract double volume();
}


public class Sphere extends Shape {
    public double radius = 5;
    private double sphere_Volume; 
    public double sphere_SA;
    
    @Override
    public double surface_area() {
        sphere_SA = (4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2));
        return sphere_SA;
    }

    @Override
    public double volume() {
        sphere_Volume = (4/3 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3));
        return sphere_Volume;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String SA_String = String.valueOf(sphere_SA);
        return SA_String;
    }
}

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ShapeArray {
    public static void PrintShape (ArrayList<Shape> shapeArray) {
        for (int i = 0; i < shapeArray.size(); ++i) {
            System.out.println(shapeArray.get(i));
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Shape> shapeArray = new ArrayList<Shape>();
        
        shapeArray.add(new Sphere());
        shapeArray.add(new Cylinder());
        shapeArray.add(new Cone());
        
        PrintShape(shapeArray);
    }

}


I tested the surface area and volume functions to see if they were operating correctly by creating an instance of the sphere object and using the .get method to see the sphere_SA value, and it is correct, however, when running it through the PrintArray function, it just returns zeros.

I figured it out. Instead of assigning a variable – SA_string – to the value I wanted to convert, I simply moved the function into the string.valueOf() method.
public class Sphere extends Shape {
    public double radius = 5;
    
    @Override
    public double surface_area() {
        return (4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2));
    }

    @Override
    public double volume() {
        return (4/3 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3));
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String SA_String = String.valueOf(surface_area());
        String volume_String = String.valueOf(volume());
        return "Sphere of radius " + radius + ": Surface area = " + SA_String + ", Volume = " + volume_String;
    }
}


This is necessary because the fields aren't set until you call those methods. You could get rid of the fields entirely and just call the methods in the expression for the toString, or since the radius is a constant (or is at least known at object creation time), you could just set the volume and surface area in the constructor.

@DavidConrad it's best never to calculate it if not needed, and calculate it exactly once if it's needed one or more times. A flag for initialized could be used by the stringifier method, see my answer. The idea is that it is true that calculating these values is simple here, but it could be time-consuming for some shapes, so it's best to be doing the calculation only once if needed and 0 times if not needed.

Kaleb, this way you do the calculation each time toString is invoked. So, if you invoke it 1000 times, then it computes it 1000 times. It is much better to perform the computation once if needed, save the results and reuse them rather than repeating the computation, and, to never do the computation if you do not need it.

@LajosArpad perhaps but that lazy calculation would be in another subclass of Shape. There's no reason not to calculate it here, or even just hardcode it as a constant since the radius is a constant.

It's a bad practice to calculate something multiple times. Hard-coding is even worse and radius is declared as public double radius = 5;, which is not a constant. It is not changed in the current version of the code, but it can be passed to a constructor in the future. And then the hard-coded stuff will become junk. I do not think that it is viable or wise not to have a method that computes the calculation and not to guarantee that it is executed once maximum.

You only provide a value to sphere_SA inside surface_area and to sphere_Volume inside volume. Since you did not call these methods before you converted your objects, these values are left uninitialized. A neat solution is to have a boolean for initialized and if not, then perform initialization at your first toString call, like:
    protected boolean initialized = false;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (!initialized) {
            surface_area();
            volume();
        }
        return "Volume is " + sphere_volume + " area is " + sphere_area;
    }

The idea is to compute the values exactly once, save the result and reuse it whenever you want to get the string.
